# R: How to keep only desired word from the string?

Tags: r, string, gsub

From the URL column I need keep word "export" or "import" if it exist in the  string

```
df <- data.frame (URL  = c("export-180100-from-ec-to-us", "import-420340-to-ir-from-es","export","Product"), X = c(100,200,50,600))

                          URL   X
1 export-180100-from-ec-to-us 100
2 import-420340-to-ir-from-es 200
3                      export  50
4                     Product 600
```

Expected output

```
    URL    X
1 export   100
2 import   200
3 export   50
4 Product  600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sub` from base R where by replace 0 or more characters after - with empty string, ie `-.*` is replaced by `''`

```
transform(df, URL = sub('-.*','',URL))

      URL   X
1  export 100
2  import 200
3  export  50
4 Product 600
```

Comment: I need to specify that the code has to apply ONLY rows which include "import" or "export". Now it applies to every row

Comment: @JohnOwen you can use group captures ie `sub("(export|import)-.*", "\\1", URL)`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `trimws` in `base R`

```
df$URL <- trimws(df$URL, whitespace = '-.*')
df$URL
[1] "export"  "import"  "export"  "Product"
```